# How to check for real liferay user after altering the request through Burpsuite

Tags: cookies, request, liferay

I'm doing some vulnerability check on Liferay by using Burpsuite.
Through burpsuite, i changed the Get: request and the cookie

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=8415D05C1E66F72CE8803607B6FEC26B.node1; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; USER_UUID="2n3duSU0cr8TgknmHzm8ghmRUS2LVJfx6zmuvGFspuY="; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; LFR_SESSION_STATE_2983586=1431672874448; COMPANY_ID=10154; ID=79307664464f436b414f657133626843444f577a65773d3d;
```

from one user to another. The page then loads as if the user is the other user which i copied the request from.

I tried checking for current user using ThemeDisplay, serviceContext.getUserId, request.getRemoteUser, but am unable to get the Real User before i "hacked" changes in the request.

How am I able to get the real user if the request parameters and coookies get altered?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing here... if you're coming with the session ID of user A, that's the user that's logged in. If it's user B's session id, this is the one - right? Please give more detail on what you actually check and what you expect.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to protect against a situation where a hacker sniffs  the traffic and steals a user's cookie while the user is logged in. So I've tried to simulate this situation using burpsuite. 

The checking is done on Owner Only pages so I'm trying to re-validate the user in the code by getting the current user details, but this fails as the session has already been hijacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (rightfully) can't trust the network connection between server and browser, just switch to https - problem solved. Whatever public information is exchanged can be faked in addition to the session cookie. If you only communicate on an encrypted channel, you'll need to have the attacker *on* the server or *on* the client machine. And all bets are off then anyway.

The session id cookie is http's way to communicate state between the browser and the server in an otherwise stateless protocol. If that can be spoofed, no other means of (also public) information can replace this pseudo-random number - so you'll need to keep it private.

Check [this article](https://www.olafkock.de/ok/2014/12/30/http_and_https_mixed_mode_configuration.html) and [this Liferay App](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/27551660) by yours truly on the issues of https as well as mixed mode (http/https). Spoiler alert: Mixed mode typically does not work. At least it doesn't solve the problem you expect it to solve.